# How to delete/create databases in Neo4j?

Tags: database, neo4j, nodes, sql-delete, relationships

Is it possible to create/delete different databases in the graph database [Neo4j](http://neo4j.org/) like in MySQL? Or, at least, how to delete all nodes and relationships of an existing graph to get a clean setup for tests, e.g., using shell commands similar to `rmrel` or `rm`?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You can just remove the entire graph directory with `rm -rf`, because Neo4j is not storing anything outside that:

```
rm -rf data/*
```

Also, you can of course iterate through all nodes and delete their relationships and the nodes themselves, but that might be too costly just for testing ...

Comment: And if you iterate over all nodes, it could be a good idea to let the reference node stay.

Comment: OK, thanks. I already realized this way of erasing all data, but i wasn't sure that this is the 'official' way of doing so...  ;-)

Comment: Where's the graph directory located?

Comment: @Pramod its in the data directory of the neo4j directory.  You can't miss it

Comment: On MacOSX with homebrew: /usr/local/Cellar/neo4j/community-1.9.2-unix/libexec/data

Comment: In C:\Users\USER_NAME\Documents\Neo4j on Windows.

Comment: @Ashley Thanks, sometimes it's quite a journey to find where a brew installed lib drops stuff!

Comment: @Pramod /var/lib/neo4j/data/ on Ubuntu.

Comment: Path was changed on Mac: `rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar/neo4j/2.1.7/libexec/data/*`

Comment: Perhaps it's a good idea to stop your neo4j server before doing this command.

Comment: Users of the Neo4J Web UI take note: **deleting the data directory WILL wipe your command line history!** To safely delete your database while keeping the Web UI commandline history intact, use `rm data/graph.db`

Answer (score 100):

even more simple command to delete all nodes and relationships:

```
MATCH (n)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-()
DELETE n,r
```

Comment: +1 for the statement. But be aware, just because you delete all the nodes, doesn't mean the labels you used are completely forgotten. The browser will still show all the labels. Ditto for node properties and relationship labels.

Comment: @DilumRanatunga 1. do you know how to make neo forget the labels? 2. how can node properties persist if the nodes are deleted, or relationship labels persiste of the relationships are deleted?

Comment: I don't mean the actual values; I mean the property names themselves.

Comment: there may be not only nodes and edges, but also indexes in the DB, and it's more difficult to get rid of those. also, i just managed to ruin a DB instance by massive repeated testing including deletions and it looks like physically deleting the DB files and having Neo4J recreate them on restart brings a clear improvement in performance.

Comment: I got out of memory on neo4j in docker container.

Comment: The browser doesn't keep all labels/properties after deletion, it only keeps the ones that have indexes or constraints. to truly reset the DB, you must also delete the indexes/constraints. You can delete them all with an apoc procedure, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52593664/how-to-delete-all-indexes-in-neo4j

Comment: Yes, this is a simple and more graceful approach than the previous one mentioned above viz. "rm-rf".

Answer (score 52):

## From Neo4j 2.3,

We can delete [all nodes with relationships](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-delete.html#delete-delete-all-nodes-and-relationships),

```
MATCH (n)
DETACH DELETE n
```

Currently there is no any option to create multiple databases in Noe4j. You need to make multiple stores of Neo4j data. See [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25660146/1045444).

Comment: Best answer if you don't want to resort to the file system.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it won't delete Constraints nor indexes

Answer (score 47):

Creating new Database in Neo4j

Before Starting neo4j community  click the browse option

[image]

and choose a different directory

[image]

[image]

and click start button.

[image]

New database created on that direcory

Answer (score 13):

quick and dirty way that works fine:

```
bin/neo4j stop
rm -rf data/
mkdir data
bin/neo4j start
```

Answer (score 11):

For anyone else who needs a clean graph to run a test suite - https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-clean-remote-db-addon is a great extension to allow clearing the db through a REST call. Obviously, though, don't use it in production!

Comment: It seems to delete node 0. How do I recreate it?

Comment: Actually, it skips the reference node (https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-clean-remote-db-addon/blob/master/src/main/java/org/neo4j/server/extension/test/delete/Neo4jDatabaseCleaner.java#L54). But if your reference node is gone (and you need it) you'll need to start with a clean data dir, since there isn't a `setRefenceNode()` call yet (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7186832/recreate-reference-node-in-a-neo4j-database).

Answer (score 7):

Run your test code on a different neo4j instance.

1. Copy your neo4j directory into a new location. Use this for testing. cd into the new directory.
2. Change the port so that you can run your tests and use it normally simultaneously. To change the port open `conf/neo4j-server.properties` and set `org.neo4j.server.webserver.port` to an unused one.
3. Start the test server on setup. Do `./neo4j stop` and `rm -rf data/graph.db` on teardown.

For more details see [neo4j: How to Switch Database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888280/neo4j-how-to-switch-database) and the [docs](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/server-configuration.html#_neo4j_database_performance_configuration).

Answer (score 6):

In Neo4j 2.0.0 the ? is no longer supported. Use OPTIONAL MATCH instead:

```
START n=node(*)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-()
delete n,r;
```

Answer (score 6):

Easiest answer is: **NO**

The best way to "start over" is to

- move to another empty data folder

or

- close Neo4j completely
- empty the old data folder
- restart Neo4j and set the empty folder as the data folder

There is a way to delete all nodes and relationships (as described [here](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-delete.html#delete-delete-all-nodes-and-relationships))

```
MATCH (n)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-()
DELETE n,r
```

Answer (score 2):

As of version 3 I believe it is now possible to create separate database instances and thus their location is slightly different.

Referring to:https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-import-csv/

> The --into retail.db is obviously the target database, which must not contain an existing database.

On my Ubuntu box the location is in:

`/var/lib/neo4j/data/databases` where I currently see only `graph.db` which I believe must be the default.

Answer (score 2):

If you have very large database,

```
`MATCH (n) DETACH DELETE n`
```

would take lot of time and also database may get stuck(I tried to use it, but does not work for a very large database). So here is how I deleted a larger Neo4j database on a linux server.

1. First stop the running Neo4j database.

   `sudo neo4j stop`
2. Second, delete the **databases** folder and **transactions** folder inside **data** folder in **neo4j** folder. So where to find the **neo4j** folder? You can find the neo4j executable path by executing `which neo4j`. Check for **data** folder going through that path (it is located inside **neo4j** folder). And go inside the **data** folder and you will see **databases** and **transactions** folders.

   `rm -rf databases/`        `rm -rf transactions/`
3. Restart the Neo4j server

   `sudo neo4j start`

Answer (score 1):

In 2.0.0 -M6 You can execute the following Cypher script to delete all nodes and relations:

```
start n=node(*)
match (n)-[r?]-()
delete n,r
```

Comment: Unfortunately this produces an error in the latest 2.0.0 release: SyntaxException: Question mark is no longer used for optional patterns - use OPTIONAL MATCH instead (line 1, column 26)
==> "start n=node(*) match (n)-[r?]-() delete n,r"

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes, since the answer says clearly *In 2.0.0 -M6*, which was the latest version when I answered the question, while other provided correct answers for the *currently* latest build.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete your data files and if you want to go through this way, I would recommend delete just your graph.db, for example. Otherwise your are going to mess your authentication info.

Answer (score 0):

Create a New DB
dbms.databases.my_new_database_name=neo4j

Switch B/w Databases
USE my_new_database_name

Delete a DB
MATCH (n)
DETACH DELETE n