# Recreate reference node in a Neo4j database

Tags: neo4j

I accidentally deleted node 0, which was my reference node on a new graph, so calls to  `getReferenceNode()` would fail afterwards. I searched through the Neo4j source and found a that I could recreate it using:

```
GraphDatabaseService graphDb = new EmbeddedGraphDatabase("mytestdb");    
((EmbeddedGraphDatabase) graphDb).getConfig().getGraphDbModule().createNewReferenceNode();
```

Am I missing a better way to recreate the reference node? Sometimes it gets an id of 0, sometimes 5 when I run this, depending on what other nodes exist. Also, comments around `getConfig()` say that it may be removed in future releases.

Comment: What's the use case for this? The different id shouldn't be a problem, just compare nodes to the actual reference node and don't check for id 0.

Comment: Right, I am fine with whatever node is my reference node.I was hoping for a setReferenceNode() method that is like the existing getReferenceNode(), or some method that maybe I am missing since the way I set it above sounds like I will not be able to call getConfig() in a future release of neo4j.

Comment: If that method goes away I'm sure there'll be another one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some time has passed since you asked this, but for your information there was some semi-recent [discussion about reference nodes in a Neo4j GitHub issue](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/175) - in summary, Peter Neubauer (Neo Technology employee) discusses either removing the concept of reference nodes, or adding a `setReferenceNode()` API call.

There doesn't seem much conclusion from that thread, but to answer your question literally, right now you're not missing a better way to recreate the reference node - hopefully one will be coming soon!

Comment: Some more time has passed and I hit a 404... :/

Comment: The reference node was removed as of [2.0.0.RC1](http://blog.neo4j.org/2013/11/neo4j-200-rc1-final-preparations.html)