# Neo4J HelloWorld is not working

Tags: neo4j

I am new at Neo4J and following the HelloWorld tutorial on the neo4j website ( http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/tutorials-java-embedded-hello-world.html).

My purpose is to create 2 nodes and a relationship between them and finally observe this on the dashboard accessible via

```
[http://localhost:7474/webadmin/#]
```

But the problem is that i am getting an error when i run my code and i don't know how to solve it.

Any help would be really appreciated

Thank you very much

Here is my code and the error

**Code**

```
import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Node;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Relationship;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.RelationshipType;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Transaction;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory;

public class HelloNeo4J {

private static enum RelTypes implements RelationshipType
{
    KNOWS
}

public static String DB_PATH= " /home/anas/graph/data/graph.db/" ; 

public static void main ( String[] args){

    GraphDatabaseService graphDb= new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase( DB_PATH );
    Node firstNode, secondNode;
    Relationship relationship;

    Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx();
    try
    {
        firstNode = graphDb.createNode();
        firstNode.setProperty( "message", "Hello, " );
        secondNode = graphDb.createNode();
        secondNode.setProperty( "message", "World!" );

        relationship = firstNode.createRelationshipTo( secondNode, RelTypes.KNOWS );
        relationship.setProperty( "message", "brave Neo4j " );
        tx.success();
    }
    finally
    {
        tx.finish();
    }

}
}
```

**Error**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Failed to transition org.neo4j.kernel.AbstractGraphDatabase$DefaultKernelExtensionLoader@691f36 from NONE to STOPPED
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.init(LifeSupport.java:388)
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.init(LifeSupport.java:82)
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:116)
at org.neo4j.kernel.AbstractGraphDatabase.run(AbstractGraphDatabase.java:224)
at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:79)
at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:70)
at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:195)
at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:56)
at HelloNeo4J.main(HelloNeo4J.java:20)
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: class org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase overrides final method getStoreDir.()Ljava/lang/String;
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
at org.neo4j.index.lucene.LuceneIndexProvider.load(LuceneIndexProvider.java:65)
at org.neo4j.kernel.AbstractGraphDatabase$DefaultKernelExtensionLoader.loadIndexImplementations(AbstractGraphDatabase.java:1180)
at org.neo4j.kernel.AbstractGraphDatabase$DefaultKernelExtensionLoader.init(AbstractGraphDatabase.java:1152)
at  org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.init(LifeSupport.java:382)
    ... 8 more
```

Comment: Which version of Neo4j are you using? Maybe your version is different than the example code.

Comment: i am using this one : Neo4j - Graph Database Kernel 1.8.2

Comment: The link your referring to is for the 1.9.M05 version. Maybe try the example code for 1.8.2? See http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/1.8.2/tutorials-java-embedded-hello-world.html.

Comment: You were right, it seems it was a version issue.
the first time i run it, i got no error , but nothing's been added to db
the second time i got this error (which disappear when i delete the graph folder) 
Mar 27, 2013 4:44:05 PM org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaLogicalLog doInternalRecovery
INFO: Non clean shutdown detected on log [/home/anas/graph/data/graph.db/nioneo_logical.log.1]. Recovery started ...

Comment: Actually , i got no error , but nothing has been added to the database ! i mean i didn't see the nodes i created on the dashboard !

Comment: Can you go to the "data browser" tab and enter "START n=node( * ) RETURN count( * )". What's the result?

Comment: i am having as a result 1, which seems to be the root node

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues,

First: INFO: Non clean shutdown detected on log ... Recovery started

The information you see, is because you didn't cleanly shut-down your database with db.shutdown(), so it has to recover non-applied transaction logs.

Second:

If you want to see your results in the Neo4j-Server you have to use the same db-directory as in `conf/neo4j-server.properties` and you **MUST** stop the server while you are writing data to it.

Oherwise you can also run the server on top of your embedded db, see: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/server-embedded.html

Comment: Thanks Michael !
Actually i was afraid that the injection of nodes wasn't successful as i didn't see anything on the dashboard. But i could verify it through the neo4j-shell by selecting the database path i used in my java code, and got my data using a simple cypher query on it

Comment: Hello again, 
i changed the path-to-db in my code to the path `/db/data/` used by the Neo4J server and that is located in the file `conf/neo4j-server.properties` 
Nevertheless, i can **only** check on the **shell** that inserts have succeed, but i still cannot see this on the **Neo4J administration interface**.

Could you give me more details about this please ?

Comment: I found the solution here 

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888280/neo4j-how-to-switch-database`

Comment: So, to observe the data in the graph database, i have modified the file `conf/neo4j-server.properties`and changed the line which references the database that is being used by the neo4j server like this: `org.neo4j.server.webadmin.data.uri="path-to-the-database" `.            

`path-to-the-database` was in my case `" /home/anas/graph/data/graph.db/"`

Answer (score 0):

Please implement a graph database (a kind of NoSQL). This graph database 
should consist of nodes (with have properties) for entities and edges (which 
have single or multiple properties and can be directional or bidirectional) for 
relationships, and support node indexing and query. The query language has 
following keywords: START, MATCH, WHERE, RETURN, ORDER BY, 
AGGREGATE, SKIP, and LIMIT.