# When using Neo4j embedded in a tc-server instance database is not shut down cleanly

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

It appears that shutdown() is not being called properly on my embedded neo4j database when tc server is stopped (just running this within STS).

Here is the log message I see:

```
16:03:43.358 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  neo4j.xafactory - Non clean shutdown detected on log [/home/billy/target/data/graph.db/nioneo_logical.log.1]. Recovery started ...

INFO: Non clean shutdown detected on log [/home/billy/target/data/graph.db/index/lucene.log.1]. Recovery started ...
```

I searched the Spring forums and SO for similar issues and all I found was [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15662059/neo4j-helloworld-is-not-working/15668671#15668671)

However I don't think that is relevant here as Spring should be handling this when the context is shutdown.

```
<neo4j:config storeDirectory="target/data/graph.db"/>
<neo4j:repositories base-package="com.example.repository"/>
```

The XML Parser for this tag clearly registers the shutdown() destroy method on the bean.

```
 private String handleStoreDir(Element element, ParserContext context, BeanDefinitionBuilder configBuilder) {
        String storeDir = element.getAttribute("storeDirectory");
        if (!hasText(storeDir)) return null;

        BeanDefinitionBuilder graphDefinitionBuilder = BeanDefinitionBuilder.rootBeanDefinition(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.class);
        graphDefinitionBuilder.addConstructorArgValue(storeDir);
        graphDefinitionBuilder.setScope("singleton");
        graphDefinitionBuilder.setDestroyMethodName("shutdown");
        context.getRegistry().registerBeanDefinition(GRAPH_DATABASE_SERVICE, graphDefinitionBuilder.getBeanDefinition());
        configBuilder.addPropertyReference(GRAPH_DATABASE_SERVICE, GRAPH_DATABASE_SERVICE);
        return GRAPH_DATABASE_SERVICE;
    }
```

Also don't be confused by my log message my DB is not actually in the webapps directory the path to the application on the app server is actually:

/home/billy/DevTools/springsource/vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.8.2.RELEASE/base-instance/wtpwebapps

Has anyone else encountered this issue, and figured out how to solve it?  For my small example application it is not a big deal but it is not a message I want to see if I choose this technology for my production application.

Comment: Are you sure this is a Neo4j problem? Can you test with an empty Java Bean witha a shutdown() method and a log printout to set this? It might be Tomcat not calling the Spring shutdown sequence properly.

Comment: Peter you are right its most likely not a Neo4j issue.  I did not see this with a stand alone application.   It happened when I decided to wire up a web application with Spring-neo.  It looks like the shutdown hooks are not being executed when I stop tc-server.  I guess I can try to set some break points in Spring and the Neo4j shutdown method and see if I actually hit them when I stop the server.  I am not sure how well that will work though since things are shutting down but I will give it a try and post back.

Comment: I ran a quick test here at work in STS with a TCServer instance.  I created a @PreDestory method in a spring bean right clicked the server and selected stop.  The method was not called.  I have a sneaking suspicion that stop (not terminate) is just killing things and not issuing a graceful shutdown sequence.  When I get home I will try to deploy the application to an appserver outside of the embedded one in the IDE and see if I have any joy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Peter is right.  This is not an issue with Neo4j or even with Spring Neo4j.  Apparently when running a local developer copy of tc-server within STS and choosing to stop the server, STS hard kills it rather than sending a shutdown signal which would have otherwise caused a context destroyed event to be sent to the dispatcher servlet.  Therefore the lifecycle events are never called on the Spring context and nothing gets cleaned up.  This really should be an issue on the STS issue tracker. I will most likely follow up on this when I get a few moments.