# Unable to switch neo4j database

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I am new in neo4j and i am using  "**neo4j-community-3.0.1**" . I want to switch database and retrieve nodes .After google i found [how to switch database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888280/neo4j-how-to-switch-database)  . But there is no file with name

**conf/neo4j-server.properties**

There are two files neo4j.conf and neo4j-wrapper.conf . But there is not any configuration such
**org.neo4j.server.database.location=data/graph.db**

Can any one help me how to switch database and i am able to see node using 
browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Neo4J 3.0, all the configuration files have been streamlined and unified into one file. Which is "**neo4j.conf**".

**You need to change the DB path in this file.**

If you are using Linux the file can be found at

> /etc/neo4j/neo4j.conf

The actual entry you need to change will be

> dbms.directories.data=/var/lib/neo4j/data

If you are using the windows client for Neo4J Community. You should have an option to browse to a database directory before starting the database.

Quoting this link.
http://neo4j.com/blog/neo4j-3-0-massive-scale-developer-productivity/

"The new file, config and log structures in Neo4j 3.0 are designed to streamline operations and to bring Neo4j better into line with operational IT expectations. One notable change is to move from multiple config files to a single namespaced files."

The ops manual might also be of use to you.
http://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/

Comment: It's tacky to tell people to upvote and mark as answer. People will vote based on what you post.