# How can I change database in Neo4J version 3?

Tags: neo4j

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 with Neo4j version 3 and I'm trying to import data using [this](https://github.com/jexp/batch-import) **batch importer**.

I've followed the tutorial and I managed to create **test.db**.

My question is: how do I make `test.db` the database used by neo4j?

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37495851/can-not-able-to-switch-neo4j-database) question says to change this line `dbms.directories.data=/var/lib/neo4j/data` inside 
 `/etc/neo4j/neo4j.conf`file.

How should I change `dbms.directories.data=/var/lib/neo4j/data`?
Inside `/var/lib/neo4j/data` I have 2 folders: `databases` and `dbms`. Do I have to move my `test.db` folder inside the `databases` folder (which contains a `graph.db` folder) or what?

I tried moving `test.db` inside the data folder (at the same level of `dbms` and `databases` folders) and I changed the line in `dbms.directories.data=/var/lib/neo4j/data/test.db` but it seems it  doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the typical directory structure within the `data` directory:

```
data
-- databases
---- graph.db
```

Where `graph.db` is a directory containing the Neo4j store files (what the batch importer creates).

You can either move `test.db` into `data/databases` and rename it to `graph.db`, replacing the existing directory (no config changes needed) or, if you move `test.db` into `data/databases` such that you have:

```
data
-- databases
---- graph.db
---- test.db
```

Then you will need to set `dbms.active_database=test.db` in `neo4j.conf`

Also it is worth pointing out that Neo4j ships with an official version of the batch importer. You can learn more about that [here](http://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tutorial/import-tool/).