# create database equivalent in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I'm new to neo4j. I need to run several different applications against a single neo4j instance.

For example the equivalent in the MySQL world, would be if I had a petstore application, a wordpress blog and a calendar application, I would simply:

```
create database petstore;
grant all privileges on petstore.* to 'petstore'@localhost identified by 'sompass'

create database mywrodpressite;
grant all privileges on mywrodpressite.* to 'mywrodpressite'@localhost identified by 'sompass';

create database mycalendar;
grant all privileges on mycalendar.* to 'mycalendar'@localhost identified by 'sompass';
```

My three applications would be insulated from each other.

Question:
  How do I accomplish this scenario using Neo4j?

There is a similar questions asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498523/how-to-delete-create-databases-in-neo4j), but I think the answers are not relevant to what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neo4J does not enforce security on the data level.

You can, however, implement a [`SecurityRule`](http://components.neo4j.org/neo4j-server/stable/apidocs/org/neo4j/server/rest/security/SecurityRule.html) and register it on the server.

Consult the [security chapter](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/security-server.html) of the Neo4J manual for further information about this.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. As a follow on -- should I:
 add properties to each node and edge for each applicaiton say: app=mypetstore, app=mywordpresssite, ... and then enforce filters on my queries?

Comment: ...or place each apps data in its own sub-graph.