# neo4j : Is there any such command is neo4j like 'CREATE DATABASE'

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to create a new Database in neo4j using Cypher as I am not a Java (or Programming language) guy but a Database person ....Could I create a neo4j database using Cypher before creating nodes and relationships ...I am using ne04j community console and would like to create a new database

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only one database.

You can clean out your current data by either stopping the server and removing the database on disk `/path/to/neo4j/data/graph.db` and starting it again.

Or by executing a Cypher statement like:

```
MATCH (n)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]->()
DELETE n,r
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to create a new database as`(neo4j folder)\data\graph.db` is the default path for the database.Neo4j is different from the relational databases.Folder it self is a database.In a graph database you have to create three things: nodes,relationships and properties.

If you want to change the database path you can change the path in conf/neo4j-server.properties.

You can also refer below link:
[How to delete/create databases in Neo4j?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498523/how-to-delete-create-databases-in-neo4j)