# Creating multiple databases on one server using Neo4j

Tags: database, neo4j

How do you create multiple databases on one server using neo4j?
I have multiple clients, and I want to separate all client information into different database to avoid data leaks.

Comment: You can copy-paste the main folder of neo4j server. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58751637/3209523

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You need to have multiple Neo4j installations with a different port configurations in `conf/neo4j.properties` and `conf/neo4j-server.properties`.

Alternatively you might use some virtualization or container tool like http//docker.io for a more sophisticated approach.

Comment: What's the logic behind this?  Sure I'm still blinded by my knowledge of SQL but whats the reason for only having a single DB?

Comment: what's wrong with having different processes for different things?

Comment: @StefanArmbruster more efforts to create new db and support another ports/server instance

Comment: So we need to make multiple copies of the full neo4j community directory ? One copy for each database graph ? Why is Neo4J not handling mutiple graphs like an RDBMS does for schemas ?

Comment: Yes, use full copies. There's already a open ticket for this at https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/266.

Comment: how do i make another neo4j installation? surely apt-get does not let you change the install location?

Answer (score 11):

or add a special `label` to each node for a client, e.g. `:ClientName`.
or create a root node for each clients database, and always begin the querying at the first node.

in neo4j db, you can have separate subgraphs. if you do programm your code good, there should be no reason to have such leaks.

Comment: The need to have a separate database is very real. For example in testing, you would not want to test against the main database that you are using for development (or production if someone is brave enough to do it) because each test runs with a fresh state of the database (ideally)

Comment: @TanNguyen
If you develop/test on a production server I think you might have design issues.
Cheers!

Comment: @Ash What I meant is to have 2 separate environments when testing and developing. It is obvious that testing in production is a big no no. Please read my comment careful before jumping to conclusion

Comment: Yeah sorry if I sounded rude but you really should never come to such situations. Storing multi-domain data (say, with the label "namespace" approach) in one Neo4j database is completely fine (at least with me) since the db engine manages its indices very, very good.

Comment: @Ash it's a common use case when on single server you have prod and dev/test db with no impact on prod

Comment: I am interested to know of how a root node implementation might by like, cheers. I would appreciate some examples

Comment: @decebal hi decebal, its simple. attach all nodes from database A to one "root" node, and attach all nodes from database B to another root node. querying a dataset will have to always include the particular root node for which database you want to access. this is more-less a code based solution to distinguish standalone datasets in one neo4j server instance.

Comment: also note, that a supernode with many relations (i remember having 200k and more relations few years ago, maybe the engine has been optimized to handle more these days) will slow querying. so this solution is ok for many, many sub datasets with ~100k nodes (ie 100k relations to the root node) at max.

Answer (score 8):

**Update: Apr 11 2020**
Recently (End of 2019, early March 2020) Neo4j has come up with supporting multiple database in same instance

You can manage multiple database using simple commands like below

```
:use system
:show databases
:create database exampleDB
:use eampleDB
```

Please read more about from [here](https://neo4j.com/developer/manage-multiple-databases/)

**PS:** The multiple database feature is Enterprise edition/license only, **not available for community** :-(

as @stefan-armbruster has mentioned it might be good to use multiple Neo4j docker container instances for running multiple Databases

May be below docker compose file should be able to help u in doing this

```
version: '2'
services:
  neo4j:
    image: neo4j:latest
    network_mode: host
    restart: always
    environment:
      - NEO4J_AUTH: neo4j/neo4j
    cap_add:
      - SYS_RESOURCE
    ports:
      - "7474:7474"
      - "7687:7687"
    volumes:
      - $HOME/neo4j/data:/data
```

Update: 23rd Dec 2020
if you need latest version of docker-compose, here below it is

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  
  neo4j:
    image: neo4j:4.2
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '7474:7474'
      - '7473:7473'
      - '7687:7687'
    volumes:
       - ./data:/data
       - ./logs:/logs
       - ./import:/import
       - ./plugins:/plugins
    environment:
      - NEO4J_AUTH=neo4j/neo4j
```

once you have saved the above to a docker-compose.yml, run below command

```
docker-compose up
```

if you want to run in background

```
docker-compose up -d
```

Now you should be able to access the database as `http://localhost:7474`, if you are using docker-machine, you will have to use the docker-machine IP address to access the database

By maintaining multiple docker-compose files with different ports in them, you can maintain multiple database, this is not just for neo4j, you can do it for any type of DBs (Mongo, Redis, RabbitMQ etc.,)

for specifying different docker compose file, try below command

```
docker-compose -f <your docker compose file name>
```

Comment: You can also refer this useful link https://medium.com/@slavahatnuke/neo4j-node-js-docker-docker-compose-fdc1cc9cf405#.syy5fgqbu

Answer (score 0):

Update Sept 2023: The open source DozerDB Plugin adds multi-database to Neo4j Community.   https://dozerdb.org