# How to drop a relationship type in Neo4j's Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am learning Cypher, created a lot new relationships, then deleted. But the relationship types are not "dropped", I can see them through:

http://localhost:7474/db/data/relationship/types

How do I drop relationship types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

+1 to [mif's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28145505/2055187).

After some study, this is more like switch the Neo4j DB "pointer" to a new directory.

In windows, the default db-directory is

```
C:\Users\You\Documents\Neo4j\default.graphdb
```

I created a new directory,

```
C:\Users\You\Documents\Neo4j\newDB
```

In Neo4j community window,  see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23930536/2055187)

```
1. Stop
2. Browse => select/locate to the newDB directory
3. Start
```

This reminds me of attaching/detaching DB in SQL server. Each directory is a DB, you can keep many DB in OS, seems community version can only have one current DB.

Comment: yep, neo4j keeps labels, property-names and rel-types around in case you just deleted the last of a kind and are inserting new ones in the next second.

Answer (score 3):

Right now only by deleting the db-directory.